# How to retrieve data with many to many relationship in Laravel resource

Tags: laravel

I am using Laravel 7.
I have three table with many to many relationship. The tables are `users`, `task_user` and `tasks`.
The models have the following relationships:

Task.php:

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User')
        ->withPivot('user_id', 'task_id')
        ->withTimestamps();
}
```

TaskUser.php:

```
public function task()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Task');
}

public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

User.php:

```
public function tasks()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Task')
        ->withTimestamps();
}
```

This is my controller method:

```
public function get_delayed_tasks() {
    $tasks = Task::select('id', 'name', 'description', 'deadline', 'closed_at', 'status_id', 'project_id')
        ->whereRaw('closed_at > deadline')
        ->get();

    return TaskResource::collection($tasks);
}
```

This is my resource:

```
public function toArray($request)
{
    return [
        'id' => $this->id,
        'name' => $this->name,
        'description' => $this->description,
        'deadline' => $this->deadline,
        'closed_at' => $this->deadline,
        'status' => $this->status->name,
        'project' => $this->project->name,
        'devs' => $this->relationLoaded('users') 
            ? $this->users->pluck('users.name')->unique()->all() 
            : [], //problem
    ];
}
```

Unfortunately in the key `dev` in the resource I receive always `[]`, even if I should receive an array of names.
How can I retrieve all the users that have worked with the task?

Comment: then you should load users in the Task query, Task::with('users')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to load the relationship to use it within the resource

Controller

```php
public function get_delayed_tasks() {
    $tasks = Task::with(['users']) // <-- load relationship
        ->select('id', 'name', 'description', 'deadline', 'closed_at', 'status_id', 'project_id')
        ->whereRaw('closed_at > deadline')
        ->get();

    return TaskResource::collection($tasks);
}
```

Resource

```php
'devs' => $this->whenLoaded(
    'users',
    $this->users->pluck('name')->unique()->all(),
    []
)
```

---

Advanced modification for the Resource, if you decide to create a `UserResource` to get more data:

```php
'devs' => UserResource::collection($this->whenLoaded('users'))
```

Comment: It works if you remove `users.` inside the `pluck`. Otherwise it returns `null`.

Comment: My bad, yeah of course, because you access the relation there is no need to prefix the `name` attribute with `users`